# CSS multiple input element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was trying out CSS and I do not know why my 2nd `input` follows the css ruling even though I didn't declare  in the class.

```css
.container2 input[type="text"],input[type="password"] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px 22px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="no container 1">
  <input type="password" placeholder="no container 2">
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <input type="text" placeholder="no container 3">
  <input type="password" placeholder="got container 4">
</div>
```

https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/best-code-editor/G3Dzq6Ct/1

Comment: Because you are declaring password field css without parent selector. need to add like this: `.container2  input[type="password"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code means 'text input in .container2 and all password inputs'. Add `.container2` before password too.

```
.container2 input[type="text"], .container2 input[type="password"]
```

In this case you can use simplier selector for the same result (just in this case, not in general)

```
.container2 input {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS; you start a new declaration after ",". So that you have to start with adding .container2 parent for both.

So you should use

```
.container2 input[type="text"], .container2 input[type="password"]   {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 15px 22px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```